# »sein« als Verb der Bewegung?

Tags: word-usage, verb

»Normale« Verben der Bewegung sind

> gehen, fahren, laufen, schwimmen, fliegen, robben,

usw.

Aber auch »müssen« und »mögen« werden manchmal als Verb der Bewegung verwendet:

> Da vorne **musst** du nach links.
>   Du **musst** zum Chef!
>   Ich **möchte** nicht zu Tante Luise.
>   **Möchten** Sie lieber nach Italien oder nach Spanien?

Das gemeinsame dieser Beispiele ist, dass »müssen« und »mögen« nicht nur als Vollverben (wie oben) sondern auch als Modalverben gemeinsam mit dem Infinitiv eines »echten« Bewegungsverbs verwendet werden können:

> Da vorne **musst** du nach links **fahren**.
>   Du **musst** zum Chef **gehen**!
>   Ich **möchte** nicht zu Tante Luise **fahren**.
>   **Möchten** Sie lieber nach Italien oder nach Spanien **fliegen**?

Insofern könnte man die Sätze aus dem ersten Block als Verkürzungen der Sätze aus dem zweiten Block interpretieren.

Heute ist mir aber bei einer Nachrichtensendung aufgefallen, dass auch »sein« als Verb der Bewegung verwendet wird. (Dieser Satz stammt von einem ausgebildeten Berufssprecher):

> Die Beamten **sind** ins Gebäude und haben mehrere Computer beschlagnahmt.

Auch hier kann man den Satz mit einem echten Bewegungsverb ergänzen. »Sein« verliert dann ebenfalls seinen Status als Vollverb: Es wird zum Hilfsverb.

> Die Beamten **sind** ins Gebäude **eingedrungen** und ...

**Meine Frage:**
Ist die dargestellte Verwendung einer Form von *»sein«* ohne ein Bewegungsverb eine standardsprachliche Formulierung? Wie ist das stilistisch zu bewerten?

Comment: Ähnlich: *sein + Adverb*, gerne auch die Kurzform: *Wir sind rein und …*

Comment: Das sehe ich eher umgangssprachlich bzw. sogar südlich regional.

Comment: Klingt meiner Meinung nach sehr umgangssprachlich. Analog zu "Ich so: ..." und "Und er so: ..." wo das "sagte" fehlt.

Comment: Auch für mich ist das eine Verkürzung und Umgangssprache (und verbreitet genug, um in der Alltagssprache akzeptabel zu sein), in Schriftform würde ich es vermeiden. @tofro: meintest Du mit "regional südlich", dass es dort auch auf gehobenem Niveau als korrekt angesehen wird? Umgangssprachlich ist es jedenfalls nicht auf den Süden beschränkt.

Comment: @Volker Exakt "standardsprachlich akzeptabel im Süden" meinte ich mit "südlich regional".

Comment: Online-Duden z.B. markiert in seinen zwei Einträgen zu *sein* sein Beispiel *sie ist zur Kur* (gereist) nicht als umgangssprachlich, aber *sie sind mit dem Wagen in die Stadt* (gefahren), was für mich exakt dieselbe Verwendung ist, sehr wohl - Scheint sich also selbst nicht so ganz sicher zu sein.

Comment: Darf ich den Downvoter um ein kurzes Feedback bitten? Warum ist das eine schlechte Frage?

Comment: @Robert Ich komme zwar aus dem Süden Deutschlands, aber auch hier in der Mitte (Nordhessen) höre ich ständig Sätze "Ich bin dann wieder ins Haus, weil's mit zu kalt war" oder "Eigentlich bin ich nur in den Laden, um mal zu schauen...". Ich habe das auch in anderen Regionen gehört und würde es daher zunächsteinmal nicht auf das Niveau von "Und dann ich so" stellen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dazu *Berthele*, *Sein*+Direktionalergänzung: Bewegung ohne Bewegungsverb, in: *Geist/Rothstein*, Kopulaverben und Kopulasätze, 2007, 229, 248 (Hervorhebungen nicht im Original):

> Zuletzt soll hier noch auf die Verwendung von *sein*+Direktional in der
>   Standardsprache eingegangen werden. Eine Suche im COSMAS II-Korpus für
>   Sätze mit einer finiten Form von *sein* und - im maximalen Abstand von
>   3 Wörtern - *hinauf* liefert für diese Behauptung der **Dialektalität**
>   solcher Konstruktionen zusätzliche Evidenz. Die Abfrage ergibt
>   insgesamt 6 Belege, die der hier diskutierten *sein*+Direktional-Konstruktion entsprechen. Alle
>   Beispiele stammen aus österreichischen Zeitungen, und alle Belege sind aus Passagen mit direkter Rede [...]
>
> Für die ausschließlich österreichische Provenienz der Belege habe ich hier keine abschließende Erklärung. Sie legt aber zweifellos den Schluss nahe, dass die Konstruktion **im Oberdeutschen lebendig ist und zumindest in Österreich bis in gewisse Gebrauchsweisen der geschriebenen Standardsprache hineinreicht**. In der Schweiz wird die Konstruktion möglicherweise als so dialektal wahrgenommen, dass sie im muttersprachlichen Deutschunterricht in der Schule sanktioniert wird und auch in der Journalistenprosa nicht einmal mehr in der Wiedergabe direkter Rede angemessen scheint. Keine Zweifel bestehen bezüglich der **Zuordnung der Konstruktion zur gesprochenen Sprache**, was sie zweifellos wieder in die Nähe der vorwiegend gesprochenen alemannischen Varietäten der deutschen Schweiz rückt.

Comment: *Die Katze ist den Baum rauf.* ist völlig normale Umgangssprache. Ort: Braunschweig